# composer not working on my plugin when i upload it to my website

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hosting, composer

im working in a plugin in localhost, it works fine in my localhost website
im using composer in it but then when i upload it to my website then it trows a fatal error because composer autoload is not working, in the php file with the same name as my plugin i require the vendor autoload, the errors says that the files that i call wiht autoload do not exists i dont know to much about php or composer, i cant understand why in localhost works but not in my online website dont, the vendor file exists, as i saw in the cpanel directory and then i try to upload the same plugin to other local website an it worked fine, the problem is when i upload it to the website
this is the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Inc\Base\CreateOrDropTables' not found in /home/hoteljupiterve/test.hoteljupiterve.com/wp-content/plugins/booking-jupiter/booking-jupiter.php:35 Stack trace: #0 /home/hoteljupiterve/test.hoteljupiterve.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): activate_booking_plugin('') #1 /home/hoteljupiterve/test.hoteljupiterve.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/hoteljupiterve/test.hoteljupiterve.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/hoteljupiterve/test.hoteljupiterve.com/wp-admin/plugins.php(177): do_action('activate_bookin...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/hoteljupiterve/test.hoteljupiterve.com/wp-content/plugins/booking-jupiter/booking-jupiter.php on line 35

and this is my booking-jupiter.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @package booking-jupiter
 */
/*
Plugin name: booking-jupiter
Plugin URI: http://localhost/PluginPrueba
Description: plugin de reserva de habitaciones 
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Guillermo Marin
Author URI: https://www.hoteljupiterve.com
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: booking-jupiter
*/

// define el absolute path, lo primero que hay que hacer siempre

if ( ! defined('ABSPATH')) {
    echo 'error bro, el die mato todo ';
    die;
}

// busca a vendor en composer para usar el use y namespase

if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php' ) ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}

// activo y desactivo el plugin de manera procedural, es la forma en la que pide wordpress

function activate_booking_plugin()
{
    Inc\Base\CreateOrDropTables::create_all_tables();
    Inc\Base\CreateClient::create_client_role();
    // (new Inc\Base\CreateOrDropTables())->create_all_tables();
}

function deactivate_bookin_plugins()
{
    Inc\Base\DeactivateBooking::deactivate();
}

// ya cree las funciones y bueno estos metodos de wordpress hacen el trabajo
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_booking_plugin' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_bookin_plugins' );


// busca si exite la clase Init para darle con el registerservices y asi que todos los demas se inicialicen perro
if ( class_exists( 'Inc\\Init' ) ) {
    Inc\Init::register_services();
}
```

thats all my booking-jupiter.php, i cant activate the plugin because of that error and if use require once to the CreateOrDropTables when i try the same with the Inc/init.php. it says that the class do no exists

i just try to eliminate the vendor folder and composer.json file from the cpanel an then i did install composer from the cpanel to my plugin folder, i didnt work i got the same error

Comment: Did you try to contact [Composer Community](https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-community.md) for help? I think they are more details in this area.

Comment: no, but now im gonna do it, thanks!

Comment: Are you uploading all the contents of the `vendor/` directory? In composer it's common to exclude that directory from version control, but the folder will need to be inside the plugin files to work in WordPress.

Comment: yes, im uploading all the contents of the vendor/ directory, any other suggestion? im new so i can make some mistakes

Comment: What error messages? Please edit your question and provide all steps to reproduce.

Comment: ok i just edit my question, the error says Inc\Base\CreateOrDropTables do no exists, thats why i think the problem is with the autoloader, in my other local website the plugin works just fine,

Answer (score 1):

sorry i got the solution but never posted here, i got errors because of case sensitive with my folders, i dont know why in localhost i got no error but in my website i got the folder inc and then i got the "Inc\Base" inc !== "Inc" my bad a stupid error, thanks for all who answered